# I can't find OracleCallablestatement in ojdbc8. Is it replaced? if so with what?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I can't find OracleCallablestatement in ojdbc8. Is it replaced? if so with what?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you planning on using it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `ojdbc8.jar` dependency scope is `runtime` so classes are not available during compilation. If you need to use `OracleCallableStatement` in your code change the scope to `compile`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you recommend a good source about scopes?

Comment: See [official docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Please accept the answer if it helped.